# Generate random number in evaluation score

Tags: java, random, multidimensional-array

I have a reviewer r(i) has evaluated an object o(j), which is weighted with the assigned evaluation score e(i,j) ε[0,1]. The number of reviewers and objects are 12 each.
My question is how to generate a random number with the fix number of reviewers per object at n=4.

I am able to generate a random number with the following:

```
Random rand=new Random();

    for(i=0; i<12; i++ ){
        for(j=0; j<12; j++){
                e[i][j]= rand.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("e[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " +e[i][j]);
```

Thanks all.

Comment: and you want the evaluation-scores of the four reviewers added up? sounds like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: No, it isn't. i want to generate evaluation scores that reviewers assigned evalation score to objects but every object should have evaluated by 4 reviewers only.

Answer (score 0):

From your answer to my comment i assume that you just want to keep the 4 evaluations per object (instead of e.g. combining them through binomial distribution).

So you only have to generate 4 evaluations per object, like so:

```
Random rand=new Random();

for(i=0; i<4; i++ ){
    for(j=0; j<12; j++){
            e[i][j]= rand.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("e[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " +e[i][j]);
    }
}
```

It might suprise you that we dont need to consider the 4-of-12-reviewers and can instead use 4 specific reviewers, but that is the case because we assume the reviewers are 
[independently identically distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically-distributed_random_variables).

Comment: Is it have another way if i need to consider the 4-of-12-reviewers without assuming the reviewers are independently identically distributed?

Comment: clarification: i dont assume they area identical, i assume they are independently-identically-**distributed**. It is hard to model behavior which isn't (so it is fine if you just assume they are). Also, in a realistic test you always want to make sure they are IID, ensuring the independence by disallowing them to talk to eachother and ensuring the (effective) identical distribution by shuffling the reviewer-index.